# Beta function problems

Tags: integration, beta-function

Calculate the integral:

$$I = \int_0^1 (1-x^m)^{q-1} \cdot x^{p-1} \, dx$$

Please help me!I now the shapes of beta function but I can't solve this exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to write
$$I = \int_0^1 (1-x^m)^{q-1} \cdot x^{p-1} \, dx$$
in terms of a Beta function.

---

Let $u = x^m$. Then
$$du = mx^{m-1} \; dx = mu^\frac{m-1}{m} \; dx$$
Substituting into $I$,
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 (1-u)^{q-1} \cdot u^\frac{p-1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{m} u^\frac{1-m}{m} \; du \\
&= \frac{1}{m} \int_0^1 (1-u)^{q-1} u^{\frac{p}{m}-1} \; du \\
&= \frac{1}{m} B\left(q, \frac{p}{m}\right)
\end{align*}